# flutter future change value when inside future builder

Tags: mysql, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

hello I'm new to flutter and building my first app , can I change a value in future function in builder based on a value change then reset it to the way it was when app is terminated ?
**Archive.dart**

```
class _ArchiveState extends State<Archive> {
  Future<List<YearsMain>> downloadJSONMain() async {
    String year;
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    year = pref.getString('year');
    final jsonEndpoint = "http://msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php";

    final response = await http.post(jsonEndpoint, body: {
      'flag': 'selectmainsubjects',
      'year': year,
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List mainSubject = json.decode(response.body);
      return mainSubject.map((mains) => new YearsMain.fromJson(mains)).toList();
    } else
      throw Exception(
          'We were not able to successfully download the Main Subjects.');
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: new FutureBuilder<List<YearsMain>>(
          future: downloadJSONMain(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<YearsMain> mains = snapshot.data;
              return ListViewMain(mains);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to implement a dropdown list wo change the "year" value in the future function and when the app is closed I want that value to get back the way it was , is there any way to do that or by putting another string I don't know actually , any help  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DropdownButton` to allow users to change the year. But before, move your future logic to the initState. Use Dropdown's  "onChanged" callback to update your sharedPreferences instance and the future, inside a setState. Here's an example:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Future future;
  String selectedYear = "2020";

  @override
  void initState() {
    future = downloadJSONMain(); // or just set the "future" variable inside the "downloadJSONMain function
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          selectedYear = newValue;
          // update the future once user select a new year
          future = downloadJSONMain();
          // also save it to the sharedPrefeences here
          // ...

        });
      },
      items: <String>["2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i get back to the original value when app is closed ?

Comment: Do you mean the default value by "original"? If so, it already will use the default value you set inside the state: `String selectedYear = "2020"`. If you want to use the previous value set by the user, you are already using this way with that line: `year = pref.getString('year');`. As I showed in my code, you should save it to the preferences by using the onChanged.

Comment: can i talk to you on discord ?

Comment: there is a value that is already saved in shared prefrences before this page into year 
is there is any way to get back to it ? after app is closed ?